# Error: Unable to access jarfile checkstyle-*-all.jar

Tags: java, macos, drjava

[Image of Terminal's contents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gU7vU.png)Beginner-Level Programmer working on Computer Sci class project. Trying to run Chekstyle for my PayrollProject.java program in the terminal but its not working.

I have three files that have to do with the assignment: checkstyle-7.3-all.jar, cs149.xml and PayrollProject.java and they are all in the same FOLDER on my computer but the error says they aren't all in the same directory. Please help!

Comment: What exactly you do before you see this error message? What command you run, if any?

Comment: This is everything in my terminal:                                                                                                         Last login: Sat Jan 14 19:55:45 on ttys002
Melissas-MacBook-Pro-3:~ melissahadley$ java -jar checkstyle-*-all.jar -c cs149.xml *.java
Error: Unable to access jarfile checkstyle-*-all.jar
Melissas-MacBook-Pro-3:~ melissahadley$ java -jar checkstyle-*-all.jar -c cs149.xml *.java
Error: Unable to access jarfile checkstyle-*-all.jar